# Javascript - String concatenation

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

javascript:

```
function popup(mylink, windowname, w, h)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, "width=w,height=h,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no" );
return false;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="test.html"  onClick="return popup(this, 'Test', '400', '600')">test</a>
```

Im trying to insert variable `w` and `h` in the string but without success. What is the proper way to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why string concatenation of course!

```
"width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
window.open(href, windowname, "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no" );
```